# How to add parameters in URL of Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wrote in routes.rb like this:

```
get 'app/:name&:target' => 'apps#show', :as => :app_info
```

I want to visit "app/myapp&mytarget" and then go to apps_controller#show, this is the haml:

```
link_to app_item[:name], app_info_url(app_item[:name], app_item[:target])
```

but it returns:

```
No route matches [GET] "/app/myapp&mytarget"
```

What do I missed here?

Comment: why '&' a query string begin with `?` AFAIK perhaps you want something like this get `app/:name/:target`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to specify the URL parameters you wish to accept in the routes. Simply create the route to your controller#action, eg)

```
get 'app/:name' => 'apps#show', :as => :app_info
```

and inside your apps#show action access the URL parameters from within params[:target], there can be numerous such URL parameters and all of them will be within the params hash that rails generates for you. You are not required to mention them explicitly in the routes.

So just pass parameters into your url helper:

```
link_to app_item[:name], app_info_url(app_item[:name], target: app_item[:target])
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass like that in the path or in url

```
app_info_url(app_item[:name], app_item[:target], :params1 => "value1", params2 => "value2"......)
```