# Rails/Devise: pass param after sign_in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

In my app I use Devise for authentication. Users can be invited to **sign_in** to the app through a link that has a token attached as a param.

The link looks e. g. like this:

```
https://chaos-jadz.c9users.io/tokens/?token_value=88042c1c-822e-4e80-b911-3c25a41fdc3f
```

At the moment once a user signs in the app redirects to the root path.

What I want to do now is: once a user signs in and if token_value is present then I want the app to redirect to a specific controller/action with the token as param.

I'm aware of the after_sign_in_path method Devise provides. Redirecting after sign_in to my specified controller/action is no problem. However I am not aware how to pass the param token_value also to the controller/action.

This is my sign_in form (I am using the param here as a hidden field):

```
<div class="panel panel-default devise-bs" style="font-family:arial">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4><%= t('.sign_in', default: 'Sign in') %></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name), html: { role: 'form' }) do |f| %>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :spielername %>
          <%= f.text_field :username, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "player101" %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :password %>
          <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: 'off', class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.hidden_field :token, :value => params[:token_value], class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
        <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <%= f.label :remember_me do %>
              <%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= t('.remember_me', default: 'Remember me') %>
            <% end %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
        <%= f.submit  t('.sign_in', default: 'Sign in'), class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 shared-links">
    <%= render 'devise/shared/links' %>
  </div>
```

Can you help?

Comment: This might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355767/how-to-add-parameters-in-url-of-ruby-on-rails

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps. I mean I know how to use params. My problem is that I don't know how to pass these to a new controller after sign in with devise.

Comment: i apologize, I don't have a RoR project that I can test with me, but what happens if you do the following? (in the application controller, i suppose) `def after_sign_in_path root_path, token_value => 'your data' end`

Comment: in this case nothing happens. that's exactly my problem: once devise executes the sign in it redirects but the param is gone. so i cannot use it in the after_sign_in_path method.

Comment: I think you can pass extra params in your path. Just add the extra params into brackets: root_path(mytoken: value). then retrieve it as usual: params[:mytoken] inside the targeted controller action

Comment: Ok passing as hidden field is good too. but why do you try to retrieve a param inside your view ?? `:value => params[:token_value]` is not correct.  You can retrieve params in controller only, when form is submitted. Moreover what token are you looking for ? The token that is used to confirm acount ?

Answer (score 3):

I was facing a similar, if not identical, problem trying to pass params from a Devise registration form through the default auto-login via `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)`. The goal was to route a new user to the page from which they had originally clicked the "Sign up" button. (It's an events app, and the user should be sourced back to the event they came to sign up for.)

I got it working by including a hidden form field as you did, and making sure it was permitted by including this in my ApplicationController:

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:event_token])
end
```

Then I just referenced `resource.event_token` in the `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)` block:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if resource.event_token
    event_path(Event.find_by(token: resource.event_token))
  else
    user_path(resource)
  end
end
```

So if a user signs in with an event token, it fires; if not, it doesn't.

I imagine you could do the same thing with `resource.token` to pass your params forward inside the path helper.

Answer (score 0):

if you have specific url for that controller/action then below code will work

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(current_user)
  specific_url(token: params["user"]["token"])
end
```